# Use of eval with dictionary values without breaking dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, eval

I'm trying to use `eval` with the variables from a dictionary, so the setup is very simple:

```
d = {"x": 0}
e = "x**2"
v = eval(e, d)
```

However, for some reason, this breaks the dictionary by adding an extra key, making it pretty useless:

```
print(d)
>>> {'x': 0, '__builtins__': {'__name__': 'builtins', '__doc__': "Built-in functions, exceptions, and other objects.\n\nNoteworthy: None is the `nil' object; Ellipsis represents `...' in slices.", (...)
```

This is the "expected" behaviour of `eval`, but this seems almost like a bug. So what is the most pythonic way of using dictionary key/values with `eval` without breaking the dictionary?

Comment: ...a dict with an extra key is useless? Just ignore it, or remove it if you don't want it, or pass a copy of the dict to `eval` so the copy gets the new key.

Comment: Or, of course, you could just not use `eval`.

Comment: @user2357112 It's useless in my case, because I can't use `list(d.values())` anymore (without removing the key of course).

Comment: @user2357112 What's the alternative to `eval` in this case?

Comment: Depends on the context of your program.

Comment: @user2357112 The input is a string expression `x**2+y**2` and a dictionary with `x` and `y` as keys. I could try to convert the string to code, but that seems a bit excessive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` only appears to modify the argument pass to use as the globals, not the locals.

```
>>> eval(e, None, d)
0
>>> d
{'x': 0}
```

From the documentation:

> If the globals dictionary is present and lacks `__builtins__`, the current globals are copied into globals before expression is parsed.

Comment: I've never seen `None` being passed as an argument, but this seems to be the way to do it. `eval` sure is odd!

Comment: The documentation isn't completely explicit, but the fact that the globals argument is optional implies that the default value if `None`, so you need to give it explicitly so that you can provide a value for the locals argument.

Answer (score 1):

I don't condone the use of `eval`, but...

If you don't want `d` to get mutated, how about passing in a copy of it?

```
>>> d = {"x": 0}
>>> e = "x**2"
>>> v = eval(e, d.copy())
>>> d
{'x': 0}
```